# How to find all un-imported packages in a snippet?

Tags: go

I'd like to find all un-imported packages in a given snippet, which should have been imported by `import` declarations.

For example, if I have a snippet:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("foo %d", 33)
```

in this case, find out `fmt`, so that I can do `import "fmt"` for this snippet.

I am using this,

```
// parser is import "go/parser", fset is the file contains the code
file, err = parser.ParseFile(fset, "stdin", source, 0) 
for _, ident := range file.Unresolved {
    // ident.Name is "fmt"
    // do something with ident.Name
}
```

But this will fail for snippet like:

```
var a int
```

It treat `int` as unresolved too, but it is a builtin type, why does it take it as unresolved?

Comment: Take a look at Brad's `goimports` which does exactly this.

Comment: FYI, the [goimports](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) tool does this and more. It's [source](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/cmd/goimports/goimports.go) is relatively short and clean.

Comment: Thanks, I will try goimports now.